# Reference a variable in `uses` when pointing to a path to a container

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow yml file. At the top I have a section above where the jobs are defined to make them global across jobs:

```
env:  
  DBT_REPO: ${{ vars.DBT_REPO }}
```

This var is a repo variable and I have confirmed it is already set. Pretend it's value is `fruits/apples`.

Then, in one of my jobs I try to reference this var in a step:

```
  - name: Checkout DBT repo 
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      repository: ${{ env.DBT_REPO }}
      token: ${{ secrets.WORKFLOW_TOKEN }}
      ref: ${{ env.DBT_REPO_BRANCH }}
      path: ./${{ env.DBT_REPO }}
  - name: Run DBT
    uses: ./${{ env.DBT_REPO }}/dbt-action
```

The last line is line 169.

Then, when I try to run this workflow I get an error:

> Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/main.yml#L169
> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 169, Col: 15): Unrecognized named-value: 'DBT_REPO'. Located at position 1 within expression: DBT_REPO

If I hard code it like so: `uses: ./fruits/apples/dbt-action` then things work fine. It's only when I attempt to use a variable.

How can I reference a variable in my `uses` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because the `env` context is not available to `uses`. In fact, based on documentation no contexts are available to the `uses` key.

See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability

I believe this is an architectural limitation of GitHub Actions, it appears they want to resolve all workflows/actions at the start of all jobs and thus dynamic resolution isn't possible.